# Python + Selenium: Is there a way convert Groovy based test cases into Python?

Tags: automated-testing, python, test-automation-framework, katalon, groovy

In my new project, I am supposed to bring the current test cases, all written in Groovy, to a Python base. We are talking about several thousand test cases that have accumulated over the last years.

Since the test cases are also to be extended towards API gateway testing, and since we work with Python requests here, we want and need to convert everything.

But here is the question, which I could not answer even after an intensive search:

Is there a way to convert Groovy based test cases into Python?

An example of how the tests are structured. They are pure web tests that ask for links and other questions with just one click.

Actually, it's absolutely simple, but not suitable for us for broad-based tests, even in the direction of expansion.

```
WebUI.openBrowser('my_page')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('my_page')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaking, that looks like a Katalon script. Katalon Studio basically uses scripts written in Groovy with a wrapper around selenium code.

There were some talks about enabling Python scripting with Katalon as discussed on Katalon [forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/suggest-katalon-will-support-python/25197) but as far as I know there was no progress there.